# Mathematical action on a column using list of indexes

Tags: python, dataframe

I'd like to make a mathematical action (division by 2) on each cell of column1 that corresponds to the condition col1 > 5. And I would like to save this result in df. Any ideas how to do that?

I've tried apply with lambda, but had no success, cause all the df was changed to the values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [8, 6, 2, 2],
                      'col2' : [2, 2, 1, 1],
                      'col3' : [4, 4, 4, 4]})
out = df[df_check.col1 > 5].index
```

'''

I expect the first column to look like [4, 3, 2 , 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close as you got the indices. You just need to divide the values of those indices and assign to the same indices. It will look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [8, 6, 2, 2],
                      'col2' : [2, 2, 1, 1],
                      'col3' : [4, 4, 4, 4]})
# indices where the condition is true
ix = df[df['col1']>5].index
df['col1'][ix] = df[df['col1']>5]['col1']//2

>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     4     2     4
1     3     2     4
2     2     1     4
3     2     1     4
```